# The getter 'bodyBytes' isn't defined for the type 'Future<Response> Function(Uri, {Map<String, String>? headers})'

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have updated dat to version 2.12 and I am getting this error:

**The getter 'bodyBytes' isn't defined for the type 'Future Function(Uri, {Map<String, String>? headers})'.
Try importing the library that defines 'bodyBytes', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'bodyBytes'.**

By code is like the following below:

I am getting 2 red lines below as

```
"bodyBytes": 1

"result.paths.first": 2
```

**Code**

pdf.dart:

```
class PDFApi {
  static Future<File> loadAsset(String path) async {
    final data = await rootBundle.load(path);
    final bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();

    return _storeFile(path, bytes);
  }

  static Future<File> loadNetwork(String url) async {
    final response = await http.get; Uri.parse(url);
    final bytes = response.bodyBytes;  <-- here: "bodyBytes": 1

    return _storeFile(url, bytes);
  }

  static Future<File?> pickFile() async {
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['pdf'],
    );

    if (result == null) return null;
    return File(result.paths.first);  <-- here: "result.paths.first": 2
  }

  static Future<File?> loadFirebase(String url) async {
    try {
      final refPDF = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(url);
      final bytes = await refPDF.getData();

      return _storeFile(url, bytes!);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  static Future<File> _storeFile(String url, List<int> bytes) async {
    final filename = basename(url);
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    final file = File('${dir.path}/$filename');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    return file;
  }
}
```

Comment: you mean `final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));` ?

Comment: No, i ave given the arrows to the error places, I was currently suggesting this in meta that the viewers can't see the words properly

Comment: ok is `final response = await http.get; Uri.parse(url);` your real code? or you made a typo?

Comment: yes its real before **final response = await http.get(url);** , I think i fixed it to **final response = await http.get; Uri.parse(url);**.

Comment: ok , i get it now: you changed your not compiling code to `final response = await http.get; Uri.parse(url);` if so, change it again with the code from my first comment above

Comment: Yes, it's in the line below     final response = await http.get; Uri.parse(url); on     bodyBytes

Comment: bruh then i get error under **url**

Comment: I have shown the 2 error at the start of the q. Read that b4

Comment: if you dont have any error in `final response = await http.get; Uri.parse(url);` so `final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));` will compile too

Comment: Can u look in the next line or check this one out "result.paths.first"

Comment: why aren't you telling me how to fix the 2 errors I asked in the q?

Comment: and what do you see if you type `result.` followed by `Ctrl-space`?

Comment: it shows the help bar?

Comment: plz help me with those 2 prob i have work 2 to

Comment: @pskink are you there?

Answer (score 0):

I changed `final response = await http.get; Uri.parse(url);` to final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url)); thnx to pskink and `return File(result.paths.first);` to `return File(result.paths.first!);` , then it works just fine.